# How do i lose fat and gain muscle at the same time?

Tags: muscle, weight-loss, body-fat, weightlifting

Through diet, cardio vascular exercise and using a Low Level  Laser Therapy machine I have lost 4.75St with a daily calorie deficit of approx 700 - 1100 calories below my BMR.

My BMI is now 24 (in the 'healthy' range, but close to 'overweight'), and moving forward I would ideally want to gain muscle at the same time as stripping away more fat.

I have only recently added weight training to my regime, but my concern is my body may burn the muscle I do build as opposed to my fat stores.

What would be the best approach moving forward to maximise muscle growth at the same time as maximising fat loss?

Comment: Related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/how-to-lose-fat-and-gain-muscle-at-the-same-time http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9887/what-is-the-scientific-explanation-for-beginning-weightlifters-ability-to-gain http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29774/what-should-be-the-best-plan-for-me-to-lose-fat-and-gain-muscle

Comment: Eat more protein and do resistance exercise.